# Accessing information of all my threads via a function

Tags: python-multithreading

I am working in the domain of Intelligent Vehicles and I am using threading. Basically, every vehicle is a thread and I want to implement a strategy for collision avoidance. For this, I need to access the information from both the thread, probably through a function that takes both the threads as inputs and keeps track of their position. When the absolute value of their position difference is less than or equal to threshold, one of the vehicles should stop. How can I access the information of both my threads in an easy way?

Comment: Can you at least provide some code?

Comment: @wRAR..This is actually part of my assignment at a company and I cannot provide the original code... However, here is the pseudo code..
class carthread(threading.thread):
         def __init__(self, threadID, name, port):
              
       def start():
              #Every thread receives a goal point
              #Every thread receives a constant speed
              #Every vehicles starts moving towards the goal

for carId in range(1, NR_CARS +1):
        cars.append(carThread(carId, "thread-%d" % carId, GCONTROL_BASE_UDP_PORT + carId))
    for car in cars:
        car.start()